# How to access the submitted value of a django form?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, cs50

I am trying to make an e-commerce site that allows the user to place bids through a form. The new bid that the user posts has to be larger than the listing price on the listing and any other bids. I need help accessing the value that the user submits to check if it meets the previously stated requirements.

views.py

```
def listing(request, id):
    #gets listing
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    #code for forms
    listing_price = listing.bid
    comment_obj = Comments.objects.filter(listing=listing)
    form = CommentForm()
    bid_form = BidsForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        bid_form = BidsForm(request.POST)
        new_bid = bid_form.cleaned_data.get('newBid')
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.listing = listing
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
        if (bid_form.is_valid()) and (new_bid >= listing_price):
            bid = form.save(commit=False)
            bid.listing = listing
            bid.user = request.user
            bid.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
               "auction_listing": listing,
               "form": form,
               "comments": comment_obj,
               "bidForm": bid_form
               })
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "form": form,
        "comments": comment_obj,
        "bidForm": bid_form
    })
```

(There are two forms, one for comments and one for bids.)

html

```
<!--bid form-->
    <form action = "{% url 'listing' auction_listing.id %}" method = "POST" name = "newBid">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ bidForm }}
        <input type = "submit" value = "Place Bid">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the value of the listing price by adding this line of code:
`new_bid = bid_form.cleaned_data.get("bid")` after `if bid_form.is_valid():` and created a new if statement to check if the new_bid is larger than the listing_price. I also removed `if request.method == "POST":`, which was causing an error.